# Email not sending laravel 5.8 on shared hosting using SMTP

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, config

I am using MAIL_DRIVER=SMTP and MAIL_HOSTSMTP=smtp.gmail.com. It works fine on my localhost (Xammp, Windows machine). But not worked on shared hosting (Linux machine). 
I got the error -

> Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with
>   host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]

Here is my .env file -

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=*****@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: I think to try to contact your shared hosting provider and request they open outgoing connection port 587.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya Thanks for your suggestion. OK, I will ask them to open this port. Let's see is email works fine.

Comment: I asked them and they open 465 port. But it still not working. I got same error Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101] :(

Comment: So you should change `.env` files. And set port '465'.

Comment: Here is my new .env mail config -
 
`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=465 
MAIL_USERNAME=*****@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Please have to look my answer.

Comment: have you enable allow less secure app in you Gmail setting?
https://www.dev2qa.com/how-do-i-enable-less-secure-apps-on-gmail/

Comment: @jiyush If less secure is disable then another error occurs. For this error seem like `ssl` verify_peer and verify_peer_name

Answer (score 1):

In laravel project open `config/mail.php` file and add the following line at the end of the file.

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
]
```